# Only part of dynamodb stream can be caught by lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, throughput, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I have a write to dynamodb table about 45K-50K items and enabled the dynamodb stream with batch size of 100 and trim horizon. This stream is used to trigger lambda and the lambda should be triggered 450-500 times. However only 2-3 batches can be caught by lambda, what can be the reason cause this and how to deal with it?